# Read a CSV file and Append to dictionary

Tags: python, csv

please how can I loop through all lines in the csv file RESULT4, then check the list of tuples BR to see if the first and second element in each tuple is a match with the values in the columns NodeA and NodeB respectively and add the corresponding value in the LOAD column into the dictionary element in BR if they match. Thank you

```
RESULT4.csv = Link  NodeA   NodeB   LOAD
               4    71001   8427    961.325492
               6    71002   71009   17.302306
              12    71004   8430    0.642499
              15    71003   8429    3.685375
              16    71006   8833    1.291624
              18    71007   71008   6.536354
              20    71009   70514   65.200511


BR = [(71001, 8427,{'lanes': 9, 'length': 0.1,}),(71003, 8429,{'lanes': 9, 'length': 0.8,}),(71007, 71008,{'lanes': 6, 'length': 0.3,}), (7100, 7104,{'lanes': 6, 'length': 0.3,})]
```

I tried this but I dont get the desired result.

```
with open('RESULT4.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
        for row in reader:
            if (BR[0][0]).find(row[1]) and (BR[0][1]).find(row[2]):
            BR[0][2]['volume'] = str(row[3])
print BR
```

The output should look thus:

```
BR = [(71001, 8427,{'volume': 961.325492, 'lanes': 9, 'length': 0.1,}),(71003, 8429,{'volume': 3.685375,'lanes': 9, 'length': 0.8,}),(71007, 71008,{'volume': 6.536354,'lanes': 6, 'length': 0.3,}), (7100, 7104,{'lanes': 6, 'length': 0.3,})]
```

Comment: How to you get the `lanes`?

Comment: @aj8uppal, how to add the load as volumes in the dictionary for the matching elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mainly your algorithm fails because you omit a second loop on your tuples list.

With this csv file:

```
Link,NodeA,NodeB,LOAD
4,71001,8427,961.325492
6,71002,71009,17.302306
12,71004,8430,0.642499
15,71003,8429,3.685375
16,71006,8833,1.291624
18,71007,71008,6.536354
20,71009,70514,65.200511
```

and this code

```
import csv

BR = [(71001, 8427,{'lanes': 9, 'length': 0.1,}),
        (71003, 8429,{'lanes': 9, 'length': 0.8,}),
        (71007, 71008,{'lanes': 6, 'length': 0.3,}), 
        (7100, 7104,{'lanes': 6, 'length': 0.3,})]

with open('result4.csv') as f:
        for row in csv.DictReader(f):
            for nodeA, nodeB, attrDict in BR:
                if nodeA == int(row['NodeA']) and nodeB == int(row['NodeB']):
                    attrDict.update({'volume' : str(row['LOAD'])})
print BR
```

I obtain this output:

```
[(71001, 8427, {'volume': '961.325492', 'length': 0.1, 'lanes': 9}), 
 (71003, 8429, {'volume': '3.685375', 'length': 0.8, 'lanes': 9}), 
 (71007, 71008, {'volume': '6.536354', 'length': 0.3, 'lanes': 6}), 
 (7100, 7104, {'length': 0.3, 'lanes': 6})]
```

I hope this can help you.

Comment: @ Salvatore Avanzo, thanks a lot, it was very helpful. Particularly pointing out why my attempts failed. Cheers